# SAS - DB2 - connection- coding

Tags: db2, sas, mainframe

Can anyone let me know how to pull data from DB2 using SAS program. I have a DB2 query and want to write SAS code to pull the data from DB2 using the DB2 query. Please share you knowledge in achieving this task.[SAS-Mainframe]. (2) Pointers in connecting to DB2(mainframe) using SAS.

Comment: Have you looked at the SAS documentation on connecting to databases and tried anything yet? Please post what you have tried so far, so that you can be helped.

Comment: Hi machan, I tried.. PROC SQL;
CONNECT TO DB2 (SSID=DBQX);
%PUT &SQLXMSG;
CREATE TABLE SASDS AS
SELECT * FROM CONNECTION TO DB2
(
SQL QUERY
);
%PUT &SQLXMSG;
DISCONNECT FROM DB2;
%PUT &SQLXMSG;   but i'm getting the following error  -- ERROR: Unable to load the DB2 Call Attach Facility.  
ERROR: A Connection to the DB2 DBMS is not currently supported, or IS not installed at your site.

Comment: You have to show those messages (including any message-codes) to colleagues, and if they have no clue (no one done it yet) to you technical support people. If the DB2 CAF is not installed at your site, or you are not allowing your SAS program to use it, or have not done the correct things in your SAS program, or to compare it, or to run it, etc, etc, then there is nothing anyone here can say.

Comment: Hi Bill, SAS program without DB2 connectivity is working fine. But i'm novice to SAS-DB2 so. How can i find DB2 CAF is installed or not on my site.

Comment: Only commenting on this since we had to recently renew licensing, you could run PROC SETINIT;RUN; This should give you all the licensing that you have installed on your SAS system (and when it expires). I would maybe look for the SAS/CONNECT license, or maybe the SAS/ACCESS licensing. Im sure someone on here can redirect if I am misleading you. I work in the DB2 environment as well...

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue is with your JCL, not SAS.  On the mainframe, jobs are run in lpars (logical partitions).  An analogy would be several computers networked together.  Each lpar(or computer) would be set up with software and networked to hard drives and db2 servers.  Usually one lpar is set aside to run only production jobs, another for development, etc.  It is a way to make sure production jobs get the resources they need without development jobs interfering.

In this scenario, each lpar would have SAS installed, but only one partition would be networked to the db2 server you are trying to get your data from.  Your JCL would tell the system which lpar to run your job on.  Either the wrong lpar is coded in your JCL or your job is running in a default lpar which is not the one your job needs.

The JCL code to run in the correct lpar is customized for each system, so only someone who is running jobs on your system will know what the code is.  I suggest going to someone also running jobs your system and tell them as you said 'SAS program without DB2 connectivity is working fine, but otherwise it is not.'  They should be able to point you to the JCL code you need.

Good luck.